Which better conducts vibration: wood or metal?
For some reason I can't get a definitive answer on this. My bedroom is on top of a garage, and every time the garage door opens/closes, the old garage opener that's positioned on the ceiling vibrates heavily and that vibration directly goes up to my room.
Currently, my bed mattress is directly on top of the floor, so I'm experiencing a lot of vibration. I think the best solution is for me to get a mattress frame. Note that I'm renting the place, and I do not own the garage. So I can't make any modifications to the garage opener or any wall insulation.
So I have this simple question: does a wooden or metal mattress frame conduct vibration better? I'm inclined to get a wooden mattress frame, but it seems that wood conducts vibration pretty well too.

Perhaps obvious, but: in any case, consider putting rubber or cloth between the feet of the mattress frame and the floor for further isolation

@llama yes I do plan to use anti-vibration pads for the feet. If only there's a queen-sized anti-vibration pad, then I wouldn't bother with getting a bed frame.

For the noise and vibration spectrum generated by a garage door opener under your rooms, I doubt that you would experience a difference between a steel and a wood frame.
For vibration isolation I would recommend a box spring be placed under your mattress, this will isolate the mattress from the floor vibrations.
Note that since the garage door opener is firmly affixed to the frame/structure of the building, it is naturally going to propagate noise into the entire building and there's little you can do about that. The right answer- installing vibration isolators between the motor head of the opener and the rafters to which it is currently bolted- is something you can't do in a rental.

So the best way is to have a bed frame, then on top a box spring, and then finally my memory foam mattress. Plus maybe anti-vibration pads beneath the feet of the frame. But how does box spring reduce vibration that comes from below? I only found results about how a box spring can reduce vibration coming from across (like someone else turning and tossing in the same bed). And also another answer said that if the excitation frequency matches the natural frequency of the box springs with you on the bed, then things could get worse. How unlikely is that?

the natural frequency of a box spring is BOING BOING BOING (once per second more or less) so no worries. and you can omit the bed frame.

I mostly agree with the previous answer, although if the excitation frequency matches the natural frequency of the box springs with you on the bed, then things could get worse.  But that is unlikely.  There is another, perhaps morally questionable option for your situation.  You used the word "old" to describe the opener.  It's often true that older motors and equipment will vibrate more toward the end of their life (worn bearings, etc).  If you could somehow accelerate this demise, it could lead to installation of a newer and quieter opening machine.

There are 2 factors to consider about vibration: elasticity and damping. The car suspension has a spring to avoid that any load is transmitted at once to the car. However it has the drawback of transform a sudden impact in a softer but longer oscillation. So, it is necessary a shock absorber to damp the oscillations.
Comparing wood or metal frame, I would say that both have some spring effect but wood is better for damping.

To answer the direct question, I don't think there is a simple answer that either metal is better or wood is better. Figuring that out probably requires to know the frequency of the vibration, the dimensions of the legs, the weight supported, the type of wood or metal, and other things.
But no matter. To solving your actual problem, I endorse niels nielson's recommendation to use a box spring, and also add to your bed a layer of memory foam type material, perhaps a mattress pad.
Also, go ahead and get that frame. Whether it's wood or metal I think it would help.
Is the mattress/frame/springs/headboard touching the wall? If yes, pull it out a bit. If no, shove it firmly up against the wall. Who knows, you might change the harmonics or the natural frequency of the bed system and reduce vibrations.
You mentioned that the opener is old. Is it a chain drive? Perhaps a bit of light chain maintenance would smooth up the operation a  bit. You could lube it up with some cheap bicycle chain lube.
